# Run test on Jenkins and Sonarqube for Spring Boot Server with Angular 4 UI

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle

I have a Spring Boot Server with Angular 4 UI, in the same repository, that can be built by gradle. My root project consist of:

```
-> frontend
-> src
-> gradle
-> build.gradle
-> Jenkinsfile
-> Dockerfile
```

Currently, the Jenkins job scans the src in the root project for the sonarqube. Here is what I have in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
sonarqube {
properties {
    // Sonar Specific properties
    property 'sonar.host.url', '' // This is the Sonar Server
    property "sonar.projectName", ""
    property "sonar.projectKey", ""
    property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths', 'build/jacoco/text.exec'
    property "sonar.sources", "./src"
}
}
```

I also wanted to scan the frontend/src for the sonarqube along with the ./src in the root project. How can I do that?

Also, how can run the tests inside frontend along with the tests in the root project?

Thanks